# Show hidden files when searching in finder

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I can see hidden files in Finder but when I search it doesn't find hidden files.

I have tried these two commands

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

I also change "File visibility" to "Invisible Items" when searching in Finder search

Can I make my searches easier than this?

Comment: It does not seem possible right now in High Sierra. Setting "Visibility" to "Invisible" would still not show hidden files in the search results. Quite possibly, the search does find them but then would not display them since they are ... invisible. 
Anyway, the only "workaround" (because it is not even that) is to create an alias to a hidden file, make it visible and then this alias will show up in the search results.

Answer (score 15):

Sadly, I never found a solution to this either. According to [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5711409/how-to-search-for-hidden-packaged-and-system-files-in-os-x) there is actually no way to do it except using comercial software. So the only other possible answer your question is 'use the Terminal'

1. Open a terminal
2. Enter this command:

   `cd <your_directory_of_interest>`
3. Find the files with a name starting with a 'dot'.

   `find . -name ".*"`
4. You can redirect the resulting list to a textfile by adding `> textfilename` to the last command. Then use that file to do whatever you need to do with the files.

Answer (score 8):

### In pre-2015 macs only:

---

There is a way to search also within hidden files:

1. Open Finder
2. Fill search box with searched text
3. Click "+" button.
4. Choose "File visibility" and your option.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I have tried that before.

Comment: Do as maseth says, but instead of "File visibility" you want "System files". Or rather, do both to be able to search everything.

Comment: Also try "System files" "are included"

Comment: neither does work to me

Comment: @DonGavel addition _does_ work. Would warrant a separate answer :-)

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: this has not been available in MacOS for ~10 years

Comment: this still works

Comment: Confirming macOs Sonoma - "System files" "are included" works perfectly fine